# How Lollipop can play compressed Audio/Video

Tags: android, audio, video, android-5.0-lollipop

From 
[Android Developers - Enhanced camera & video](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#Camera),

> Android 5.0 also adds support for **multimedia tunneling** to provide the
>   best experience for ultra-high definition (4K) content and the ability
>   to play compressed audio and video data together.

Any details or specifics of how Lollipop can play compressed Audio/Video? Also, what are the changes regarding that compared with earlier versions?

Answer (score 0):

From the sources, there is some amount of understanding as captured in this post on Google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/isNabAHLLks

To summarize, the implementation of the video tunneling is vendor/device specific implementation.

**EDIT:** The aforementioned information is for the new feature **`Video Tunneling`** introduced in `Lollipop`. The normal playback is handled through `NuPlayer` unless there is a system property employed to specifically use `StagefrightPlayer` as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp#65).

Answer (score 0):

you can get clearly concept from
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/tunneled-video-playback-in-exoplayer-84f084a8094d

If you want to know more detail, I think you could download 
AOSP project to trace the tunnel mode APIs.